# Change order of x label in facet plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot the facet plot below in alphabetical order, I've tried multiple ways of doing it and even tried getting rid of the facet and just plotting Overpaid vs proportion, but the plot still had an alphabetical x axis.

Initially I tried assigning a frequency value to every element then ordering the list by that value but that didn't change the plot.

```
overpaid_each_country <- survey_df %>%
 filter(!is.na(Overpaid)) %>%
  filter(Country %in% Country_Sum$Var1) 

overpaid_each_country <- overpaid_each_country[ , which(names(overpaid_each_country) %in% c("Overpaid","Country"))]

overpaid_each_country <- transform(overpaid_each_country, freq = ave(seq(nrow(overpaid_each_country)), Overpaid, FUN=length))

overpaid_each_country <- overpaid_each_country[order(overpaid_each_country$freq), ]
```

[image: Dataframe with frequency added]

Then I tried setting the factor levels but although the factor levels changed, the plot didn't.

```
overpaid_each_country %>% 
mutate(Overpaid2 = factor(Overpaid, levels = c("Greatly overpaid", "Somewhat overpaid", "Greatly underpaid", "Neither underpaid nor overpaid", "Somewhat underpaid"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Overpaid2, y = ..prop.., group = 1)) +
 geom_bar( color = "white", fill = "#42dff4") +
  facet_wrap(~ Country, nrow = 4)  +
  aes(stringr::str_wrap(Overpaid, 10)) +
  xlab("OverPaid orUnderpaid") +
  ylab("Proportion of Respondents")+
  labs(title = "Are you Overpaid or Underpaid?") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.y=element_text(size=12), axis.text.x = element_text(size=12), plot.title = element_text(size = 17))
```

[image: Plot with x axis in alphabetical order]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please, [edit] your question and supply a [mcve]. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In your 6th line

```
 aes(stringr::str_wrap(Overpaid, 10)) +
```

change to overpaid2

```
aes(stringr::str_wrap(Overpaid2, 10)) +
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `forcats::fct_reorder()` to re-order your factor-levels, or you change the levels from somethink like `"a"` to `"e"`, and then pass a named vector (where names match factor levels) to `scale_x_discrete()` as labels-argument.

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(
  x = factor(sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE), labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
)

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = ..prop..)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

```
labels <- c(a = "Greatly underpaid", b = "Somewhat underpaid", c = "Neither/nor", d = "somewhat overpaid", e = "greatly overpaid")

ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = ..prop..)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = labels)
```

[image]